# Possible bug - dijit/layout/ContentPane does not resize when adding widgets as children

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

Widget `dijit/layout/ContentPane` does not resize properly when adding widgets as children.

Steps to reproduce issue:

1. Open test case at https://jsfiddle.net/9eja3jtr/
2. Click 10 times button "Click me many times!".

Issue:

- `dijit/layout/ContentPane` does not resize when adding widgets as children.
  Content inserted is not fully visible.

I would need the dimensions for `dijit/layout/ContentPane` to be increased in order to accommodate new added widgets so that all inner widgets should be visible.

I think this is a bug within the dijit widget.I would like to know a workaround if any.

Notes:
I have reported bug to dojo https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/19021

```
require(["dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/TitlePane", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(ContentPane, TitlePane, Button) {
  this._contentPanel = new ContentPane({
    style: "background-color:red;"
  }, "contentPanel");

  this._titlePanel = new TitlePane({
    title: "I'm a TitlePane",
    content: "Collapse me!"
  }, "titlePanel");

  this._button = new Button({
    label: "Click me many times!",
    onClick: function() {
      this._titlePanel.addChild(new Button({
        label: "Test",
        style: "width: 250px"
      }));
    }.bind(this)
  }, "button");

  this._contentPanel.addChild(this._titlePanel);
  this._titlePanel.addChild(this._button);
  this._contentPanel.startup();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to set the ContentPane's `doLayout` flag to false.  Then it won't set a size on the nested ContentPane.  Also, remove the hardcoded 125px height.

Comment: Setting property `doLayout ` to false fixed this issue

https://jsfiddle.net/f32x4m3k/

Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

I think the clean way to workaround this is just surround your `contentpane` by a `BorderContainer` , the resize() will be triggered automatically , otherwise I'think you should recalculate all the stuff and resize all enclosing widget (without using BorderContainer)

bellow a working snippet : (I hade specified the region center for content pane to prevent errors )

```js
require(["dijit/layout/BorderContainer","dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/TitlePane", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"], function(BorderContainer,ContentPane, TitlePane, Button) {
  this._borderContainer = new BorderContainer({},"borderContainer");
  this._contentPanel = new ContentPane({
   region: "center",
    style: "min-height:125px; background-color:red;"
  }, "contentPanel");

  this._titlePanel = new TitlePane({
    title: "I'm a TitlePane",
    content: "Collapse me!"
  }, "titlePanel");

  this._button = new Button({
    label: "Click me many times!",
    onClick: function() {
      this._titlePanel.addChild(new Button({
        label: "Test",
        style: "width: 200px"
      }));
      
    }.bind(this)
  }, "button");
 this._borderContainer.addChild(this._titlePanel);
  this._contentPanel.addChild(this._titlePanel);
  this._titlePanel.addChild(this._button);
  this._contentPanel.startup();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="claro">
  <div id="borderContainer">
    <div id="contentPanel">
      <div id="titlePanel">
        <div id="button">
        </div>
        <div id="content">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make simple workaround by CSS:

```
#titlePanel {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/9eja3jtr/3/